# DerivedA pointer pointing to DerivedB

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I have a base class which serves as an interface (if I use that word correctly). The idea is that the base class has some derived classes that implement one virtual function of the base class. Then I also need another class that extends the base class (lets call it extended base). What I would like is that I can store a class derived from base into an extended base pointer.

MWE:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual double value();
}
class Derived : public Base{
public:
    double value() override {return 5;}
}
class ExtendedBase : public Base {
public:
    virtual ~ExtendedBase ();
    virtual double value2(){return 10;}
}

int main() {
    ExtendedBase * object;
    object = new Derived();
    std::cout << object->value(); //should give implementation in Derived, i.e. 5
    std::cout << object->value2(); //should give implementation in ExtendedBase, i.e. 10
    delete object;
    return 0;
}
```

With this MWE I get a compile error at the second line in the main. `error: cannot convert 'Derived*' to 'ExtendedBase*' in assignment object = new Derived();`. Part of me understands why it doesn't work (although I can't explain), but I would like to know if I can get the desired behaviour in some other way.

P.S. Sorry about the bad question name, I couldn't think of another way to keep it short

P.S.2 I know raw pointers like this are not advised. In the future I will change to smart pointers but I don't think they are needed for this simple example

Comment: Shouldn't `ExtendedBase` inherit from `Derived` instead of `Base`?

Comment: @0x5453 : Even that may not work unless he changes the value2() to value().

Comment: You can't, `Derived` doesn't inherit `ExtendedBase`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning an address to a pointer that means you should be able to access all the members of the type the pointer is pointing to through the pointer.

For ex,

```
class B {};
class D : B {};

B *p = new D();
```

now through p, at least you can access all the members of base portion of the derived class.

But in your code,

```
ExtendedBase * object;
object = new Derived();
```

object should be able to access all the members of ExtendedBase portion of the derived class. But how is it possible as derived class is not derived from ExtendeBase. So compiler is throwing error.

You need to do some changes in your code to work.

1. To make base as interface (abstract class), you need to define at
   least one member function as pure virtual.
2. If you want to access the member function of ExtendedBase through
   Base pointer, you should define same function 'val' in your
   ExtendedBase.

Below are the changes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() {};
        virtual double value() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base{
    public:
        ~Derived() {};
        double value() {
            return 5;
        }
};

class ExtendedBase : public Base {
    public:
        virtual ~ExtendedBase () {};
        double value()
        {
            return 10;
        }
};
    
int main() {
    Base *p = new Derived();
    std::cout << p->value() << std::endl;
    delete p;

    Base *p1 = new ExtendedBase();
    std::cout << p1->value() << std::endl;
    delete p1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExtendedBase` and `Derived` are each derived from `Base`. If you want to use an `ExtendedBase*` pointer to point to a `Derived` object, you will need to derive `Derived` from `ExtendedBase`.

To use a different example,

```
class Feline{
   virtual void run();
}

class Housecat : Feline{
   void run() {}
}

class BigCat : Feline{
   virtual void run();
   virtual void roar();
}
```

Here `Feline`, `Housecat`, and `BigCat` are analogous to `Base`, `Derived`, and `ExtendedBase`. `BigCat` and `Housecat` are each `Feline`, but since `Housecat` is not a `BigCat`, you can't use a `BigCat*` pointer to point to a `Housecat`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the desired behavior from a language architect perspective.
For instance, if you have

```
class Ship
{
    public:
        virtual void move() = 0;
}

class Steamboat : public Ship
{
    public:
        virtual void move() override { ... }
}

class Sailboat : public Ship
{
    public:
        virtual void move() override { ... }
        virtual void setSails() { ... }
}
```

Now, you don't want a Steamboat to become a Sailboat all of a sudden, hence:

```
Steamboat* tootoo = new Sailboat;
```

cannot be valid.
That's why your code cannot work. Conceptually.
So giving a quick fix is not possible, because your concept is not really clear.